# Warning: POST Content-Length of 25447804 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, file-upload, size

I am getting this warning when i m uploading file more than 8mb.

I have changed following to php.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
memory_limit = 128M
```

and i have restarted the apache server too.

and i am checking through ths script

```
if($_FILES["submission_file"]["size"] < 1.049e+7)
{
  echo "success";
}
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: 25447804 bytes is quite larger than your 10M anyway.

Comment: i have checked through phpinfo();it shows POST_MAX_SIZE =8M.how it can be?

Comment: Have you checked that the php.ini you modified is the one actually loaded by apache?

Answer (score 1):

You can also change it via an .htaccess file.

php_value upload_max_filesize 10M

php_value post_max_size 10M